# Scanf statement

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Hello, I was wondering why this program doesn't execute. It seems as though I've always been having trouble with performing the scanf function properly. I get the error of:

error: ignoring return value of scanf declared with attribute warn_unused_result

Note: I know there is a more efficient method for writing my current program, but that is beside the point. I want to know what this error means and why I keep getting it and possibly a solution. Thank you guys. Here is the code:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int temp;

    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    scanf("%d", &z);

        if (x > y) {
           temp = x;
           x = y;
           y = temp;
        }

        if (y > z) {
            temp = y;
            y = z;
            z = temp;
        }

        if (x > z) {
            temp = x;
            x = z;
            z = temp;
        }

        printf("%d", x);
        printf("%d", y);
        printf("%d", z);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS; }
```

Comment: Are you compiling with -Werror?

Comment: That's not generally an error, but a warning. It's telling you that you are not using the return value of scanf, which may or may not be a bug (in this case, probably not). Crank down your compiler's warning level a notch.

Comment: @Thomas: IMHO, it is correct to consider this an error. `scanf` will return the number of tokens successfully parsed into the given variables, so proceeding to use `x`/`y`/`z` without making sure they were actually given values is incorrect.

Comment: @DCoder I agree with you. I wasn't sure though because this looks like beginner code and so error checking may not have been what the OP was after. Reading over it again I think you are right.

Comment: @Thomas The human is the least predictable of communication devices. I'd suggest that this *is* a bug, if not here then nowhere else. The return value should certainly be checked here.

Answer (score 2):

The error that you get from the compilers is just what it says. In order for your application to be correct, you have to check the return value of scanf. The possible return values are described in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf).

For an explanation of what causes the error, see the "warn_unused_result" part of [gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) (quoted in Peter R.s reply).

Answer (score 2):

From the GCC documentation:

> The `warn_unused_result` attribute causes a warning to be emitted
>        if a caller of the function with this attribute does not use its
>        return value.  This is useful for functions where not checking the
>        result is either a security problem or always a bug, such as
>        `realloc`.
>
> ```
>       int fn () __attribute__ ((warn_unused_result));
>       int foo ()
>       {
>         if (fn () < 0) return -1;
>         fn ();
>         return 0;
>       }
> ```
>
> results in warning on line 5.