# c programming, why printf does not working?

Tags: c, char, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)  {
  char op;
  int arr[3];
  printf("input ");
  scanf("%d %c %d", arr,&op,arr+1);  
  arr[3]=arr[0]-arr[1]; //here
  printf("[%c] %d\n", op, arr[3]); 
  return 0;
}
```

arr[3]=arr[0]-arr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKatG.png); 
printf("[%c] %d\n", op, arr[3]);

why does not print %c ?

[image]

Comment: Please don't change code after getting answers such that the answers become invalid. And it is better to post the output as text formatted as code instead of posting screenshots.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanf statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861077/scanf-statement)

Comment: @hagello No. Its not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Please don't be assume that I did change the code after getting answers. when i edited it, there was no answer, you answer quickly than finished it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
arr[3]=arr[0]-arr[1];
printf("[%c] %d\n", op, arr[3]);
```

should be

```
arr[2] = arr[0] - arr[1];
printf("[%c],  %d\n", op, arr[2]);
```

because array indices start from 0 and end at length - 1. Using `arr[3]` leads to Undefined Behavior as you access memory locations that you shouldn't.

In your case, `arr[3]` might've been `op`. So in the examples you've given, `op`'s value is changed to 2 and 1 respectively, and thus, the `printf` tries to print an unprintable control character and the terminal displays a space as these control characters are unprintable.

Comment: Thank you !!,  great answer